A node is shoving the graph off the page - the Friday the 13th edition
In the following TikZ diagram, I have two nodes on either side of the graph of a piecewise linear function. The node on the left side is shoving the graph beyond the right margin.
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}




\begin{document}




\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=4.5in, height=4.5in, axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    xmin=-6,xmax=6,
    ymin=-1,ymax=7.96875,
    restrict y to domain=-1:7.96875,
    xtick={\empty},
    ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=7.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=7.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


\coordinate (P_-5) at (-5,32/243);
\coordinate (P_-1) at (-1,2/3);
\coordinate (P_0) at (0,1);
\coordinate (P_3) at (3,3.375);
\coordinate (P_5) at (5,7.59375);

\coordinate (Q) at ($(P_-5)!{2/5}!(P_-1)$);
\coordinate (R) at ($(P_0)!{4/5}!(P_3)$);

\end{axis}


\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (R) circle (1.5pt);

\draw (P_-5) -- (P_-1) -- (P_0) -- (P_3) -- (P_5);
\draw (Q) -- (R);

\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(P_3)!{3/5}!(P_5)$) -- ($($(P_3)!{3/5}!(P_5)$)!0.75cm!90:(P_3)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\normalsize] at ($($(P_3)!{3/5}!(P_5)$)!0.75cm!90:(P_3)$) {\makebox[0pt][l]{$y = f(x)$}};


\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(Q)!{1/5}!(R)$) -- ($($(Q)!{1/5}!(R)$)!{1.75cm}!-60:(Q)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, text width=0.75\linewidth, align=center, font=\normalsize] at ($($(Q)!{1/5}!(R)$)!{1.75cm}!-60:(Q)$) {\makebox[0pt]{An arbitrary secant}};%\\\makebox[0pt]{the graph of}\\\makebox[0pt]{$y = f(x)$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document} 


That node's width is 0.75\linewidth whatever you do with \makebox inside it.

Use the overlay option to exclude this node from influencing the bounding box. This way your graph will be exactly in the centre (works on all days):
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}




\begin{document}




\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=4.5in, height=4.5in, axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle, clip=false,
    xmin=-6,xmax=6,
    ymin=-1,ymax=7.96875,
    restrict y to domain=-1:7.96875,
    xtick={\empty},
    ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=7.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=7.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


\coordinate (P_-5) at (-5,32/243);
\coordinate (P_-1) at (-1,2/3);
\coordinate (P_0) at (0,1);
\coordinate (P_3) at (3,3.375);
\coordinate (P_5) at (5,7.59375);

\coordinate (Q) at ($(P_-5)!{2/5}!(P_-1)$);
\coordinate (R) at ($(P_0)!{4/5}!(P_3)$);

\end{axis}


\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (R) circle (1.5pt);

\draw (P_-5) -- (P_-1) -- (P_0) -- (P_3) -- (P_5);
\draw (Q) -- (R);

\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(P_3)!{3/5}!(P_5)$) -- ($($(P_3)!{3/5}!(P_5)$)!0.75cm!90:(P_3)$);
\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\normalsize] at ($($(P_3)!{3/5}!(P_5)$)!0.75cm!90:(P_3)$) {$y = f(x)$};


\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(Q)!{1/5}!(R)$) -- ($($(Q)!{1/5}!(R)$)!{1.75cm}!-60:(Q)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, align=center, font=\normalsize,overlay] at ($($(Q)!{1/5}!(R)$)!{1.75cm}!-60:(Q)$) {An arbitrary secant};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document} 



I forgot about that option. I will use it and accept your answer.

I put the text in a node that should occupy no space using \makebox[0pt]. Why is TikZ ignoring that command?

@user143462 You tell tikz to make the node .75\linewidth wide, regardless of the content. Tikz is doing exactly what you tell it to do.
